# How can I modify the DNS nameservers on aaPanel

Tags: dns, apache, server

Where can I navigate the DNS server on aaPanel platform because I just want to modify it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can on that install. From looking at the demo and reading https://forum.aapanel.com/d/20-how-to-manage-dns it looks like DNS manager is a plugin (that is only compatible with some Linux variants to boot).

So the answer would be to make sure your OS Variant is CentOS7 or higher, you get the DNS Plugin from the store and go from there. I expect there is more to it thr n that because to run DNS competently you need at least 2 machines (2 Name servers - and while it can dodily be done on 1 system with 2 IPs that really breaks spec) - and, od-course you will need to delegate the DNS to the appropriate servers at your domain registrar - so you may be better off just using your domain registrars service.

I notice you tagged this post Apachr. You should be aware that, other then sometimes to support a web interface for it, domain management and Apache (which is a web server) are unrelated.